# How do I pause and resume with a fadeLoop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, fade

I have a show and hide div fade loop that I am using like a short interactive tutorial with tips.  I can get the divs to cycle through in order; however, I would like to add a pause button inside of each tip that pauses the loop, with the ability to resume.  How do I add that functionality into my script?

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fadeLoop()
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').css('visibility','visible').hide(),
        dur = 100;

    function showDiv() {
        $("div.fader").fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 4 * 1000); // do this every 4 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
});
```

And here is my fiddle: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpNXr/6/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find the `#start` button in your fiddle so I can't test your function. What exactly does not work?

Comment: @Bergi Updated the fiddle with a start button. You can see that when you click stop, it stops the loop, but it restarts from the beginning, not where it left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by using a global variable `window.i` as the counter

```
function fadeLoop() {

    var divs = $('.fader').hide(),
        dur = 200;

    function showDiv() {
        divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == window.i % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        window.i++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 1 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;
    window.i = 0;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
```